# Shapes not centering to table cells if size of shape is redimensioned

Tags: vba, powerpoint

In the below, the circles and chevrons created in the cells of the table are centered only if the dimensions are not changed, if a constant is given later they end up misplaced. I signaled below where their parameters are set differently and cause issues, `Width:=CellWidth * 0.7, Height:=CellHeight * 0.7)` for example
Why can it be?

```
Option Explicit

Sub NavigatorX()

Dim oSlide As Slide

Dim oShapeNavigator As Shape
Dim IconDishNavigator As Shape
Dim ChevronNavigator As Shape

Dim nCounter As Long

Dim CellLeft As Single
Dim CellTop As Single
Dim CellWidth As Single
Dim CellHeight As Single
Dim CellWidth_2 As Single

Dim iRow As Integer
Dim iColumn As Integer

Dim Shp_Cntr As Single 'Center of Selected Shapes
Dim Shp_Mid As Single 

Dim NavWidth As Single
Dim EvenCell_W As Single

Dim DishCounter As Long
Dim ChevronCounter As Long

ChevronCounter = 0
DishCounter = 0

For Each oSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides

    If oSlide.CustomLayout.Name = "Section Header" Then
        nCounter = nCounter + 1

ElseIf nCounter > 0 Then

    Set oShapeNavigator = oSlide.Shapes.AddTable(1, 10, Left:=10, Top:=10, Width:=500, Height:=2)
                        oShapeNavigator.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 128, 128)
                        oShapeNavigator.Name = "Navigator " & nCounter
                                
                              
            With oShapeNavigator.Table      '@@ TABLE @@
    
                For iRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
                For iColumn = 1 To .Columns.Count Step 2
                
                        EvenCell_W = (oShapeNavigator.Width / .Columns.Count / 2) * IIf(iColumn Mod 2 = 0, 5 / 7, 2 / 7)
                                
                        With .Columns(iColumn)
                        
                               .Width = EvenCell_W
                            
                               CellLeft = oShapeNavigator.Table.Cell(iRow, iColumn).Shape.Left
                               CellTop = oShapeNavigator.Table.Cell(iRow, iColumn).Shape.Top
                               CellWidth = oShapeNavigator.Table.Cell(iRow, iColumn).Shape.Width
                               CellHeight = oShapeNavigator.Table.Cell(iRow, iColumn).Shape.Height
                               Debug.Print CellWidth
                               Debug.Print CellHeight
            
                               Shp_Cntr = CellLeft + CellWidth / 2
                               Shp_Mid = CellTop + CellHeight / 2
                               
                                DishCounter = DishCounter + 1  
                     
                            Set IconDishNavigator = oSlide.Shapes.AddShape(Type:=msoShapeOval, Left:=Shp_Cntr - CellHeight / 2, Top:=Shp_Mid - CellHeight / 2, Width:=CellHeight, Height:=CellHeight)
'                            Set IconDishNavigator = oSlide.Shapes.AddShape(Type:=msoShapeOval, Left:=Shp_Cntr - CellHeight / 2, Top:=Shp_Mid - CellHeight / 2, Width:=CellHeight * 0.8, Height:=CellHeight * 0.8)  <--- while with a different value the shape is not centered
                     
                     
                                   IconDishNavigator.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(100, 250, 140)
                                   IconDishNavigator.Line.Weight = 0.75
                                   IconDishNavigator.Line.Visible = msoFalse
                                   IconDishNavigator.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
                                   IconDishNavigator.Name = "IconDish" & DishCounter
                                   
                        End With
                 Next iColumn
                 Next iRow
           End With
'

            With oShapeNavigator.Table      '@@ TABLE @@
                For iRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
                For iColumn = 2 To .Columns.Count Step 2
            
                                
                        With .Columns(iColumn)
                        
'                                   .Width = EvenCell_W
                                
                                   CellLeft = oShapeNavigator.Table.Cell(iRow, iColumn).Shape.Left
                                   CellTop = oShapeNavigator.Table.Cell(iRow, iColumn).Shape.Top
                                   CellWidth = oShapeNavigator.Table.Cell(iRow, iColumn).Shape.Width
                                   CellHeight = oShapeNavigator.Table.Cell(iRow, iColumn).Shape.Height
                                   Debug.Print CellWidth
                                   Debug.Print CellHeight
                
                                   Shp_Cntr = CellLeft + CellWidth / 2
                                   Shp_Mid = CellTop + CellHeight / 2
                                   ChevronCounter = ChevronCounter + 1
                                                        
                     
                            Set ChevronNavigator = oSlide.Shapes.AddShape(Type:=msoShapeChevron, Left:=Shp_Cntr - CellHeight / 2, Top:=Shp_Mid - CellHeight / 2, Width:=CellWidth, Height:=CellHeight)


' Set ChevronNavigator = oSlide.Shapes.AddShape(Type:=msoShapeChevron, Left:=Shp_Cntr - CellHeight / 2, Top:=Shp_Mid - CellHeight / 2, Width:=CellWidth * 0.7, Height:=CellHeight * 0.7)   <--- while with a different value the shape is not centered



                                   ChevronNavigator.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(100, 100, 100)
                                   ChevronNavigator.Line.Weight = 0.75
                                   ChevronNavigator.Line.Visible = msoFalse
                                   ChevronNavigator.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
                                   ChevronNavigator.Name = "Chevron" & ChevronCounter
                                   

                        End With
            
                Next iColumn
                Next iRow
            
            
            End With

End If
Next oSlide

         DishCounter = 0
         ChevronCounter = 0



End Sub
```

Comment: Given that a shape's co-ordinates and dimensions are relative to its top left corner if you reduce the size of the shape, it is obvious that the center point of the shape will move.

Comment: Given that the top left position doesn't change the bottom and right sides of the shape are moved when the size is changed, just as it does when you change the dimensions in the UI.

Comment: @Tim Yet in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71179627/create-centered-shapes-beneath-selected-ones, a  previous macro I made the re-dimensioning does not affect the position, is it because they are shapes and not a table?

Comment: If I have understood your question correctly you are comparing the results of the two lines of code that add the IconDishNavigator shape. In the commented out line you set the height and width of the shape to 80% of the cell height, but do not change the top and left positions. This will result in the mid-point of the shape not aligning with the mid-point of the cell. If you reduce the size of the shape, you also need to adjust the top and left position to compensate.

Comment: @Tim, yes, I was misapplying it: by creating another variable for eac `Left:=Shp_Cntr - (CellHeight * DishRatio / 2), Top:=Shp_Mid - (CellHeight * DishRatio / 2), Width:=CellHeight * DishRatio, Height:=CellHeight * DishRatio)` etc the shapes were in the correct position

Comment: This seems like an unnecessary amount of work. Instead, consider using a symbol font to place chevron and circle characters into the table cells where they can automatically be centered.

Comment: @John, thank you for the advise, I searched round but I am not entirely sure I understood correctly, are you suggesting I use wingdings in the code? Ora that I write somewhere else their values and call them as an external function?

Comment: You can use TextRange.InsertSymbol to insert a webdings/wingdings character. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.textrange.insertsymbol Here's a Stack Overflow page with a couple of other simple alternatives to floating shapes over table cells: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15638681/powerpoint-vba-table-object-alignment